# webserver in docker containers on ubuntu

Tags: apache2, docker

I've setup a Apache,PHP webserver on Ubuntu 20.04 and I can access my site using my `domain-name dot com`. I need to setup another site on the same server however it has slightly different requirements than the existing site. I was thinking to setup a docker container to solve this issue.

So, my server is already using port 80 to serve to `domain-1`. How do I setup docker to serve `domain-2`. Is this possible? I can't figure it out.

Or the other thing I can think of is to move both sites to docker containers. In that case, how do I setup two different domains to two different docker containers?

I am new to this, so please guide.

Comment: The configuration [in this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/942908/1222991) will get you most of the way there. If you know how to set up Docker to listen on specific ports, then you’ll have everything you need 

Comment: @matigo - thank you for the link. I'll go through and see if works.